# Register while login with openid spring security

Tags: java, spring, openid, spring-security

I have followed [this demo](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with.html) implementing login using spring security and openid.

I am successful implementing it, But using spring security I have to provide the user details in the `userservice` section of `spring-security.xml`

```
<security:user name="http://krams915.myopenid.com/" password="" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

I want to implement register and login cycle through openid in one go. I am not getting how to go ahead without providing username in userservice, as the user that visits my site will not be registered previously.

Any help or guidance would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

The [`openid`](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/samples/openid/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml?hb=true) sample with spring security has some examples of using the `attribute-exchange` tag to pull data from OpenId providers. This will let you grab required data (or at least some of it) for users, especially if they are coming in new.

The [`CustomUserDetailsService`](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/samples/openid/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/samples/openid/CustomUserDetailsService.java?hb=true) in that example also shows one possible way to create new accounts in your application when new users come in via OpenId that links their OpenId identifier to a new user account within your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesnt provide solution exactly how it should work. [Here](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/spring-security-by-example-openid-login.html) is the entire solution which works fine.

Comment: @user - Yes, that example does walk through it in baby steps, but the core of what they are doing is the same as the Spring Security example I linked to. Obviously, I only linked to the specific code files that illustrated the attribute exchange and the app-local user account creation, but the walkthrough you linked to is virtually the same as the spring security example.

Comment: For this openid stuff it did the trick, now I also want to integrate Facebook, twitter, linked-in login with this, which follows OAuth.. Is it possible to integrate both of this? if yes, can you provide any links or how it can be done.? I referred [blogTrickl](http://blog.trickl.com/?tag=spring-social), but this didnt help much..

Comment: @user549757 - Check out Spring Social...It is a new project, but should meet your needs. (http://www.springsource.org/spring-social)

Comment: Yes, I know that but spring social only uses OAuth and leaves OpenID. I want both at a time. Any suggestion for that?